# How to pipe output to a rotating log file in shell, like log4j does?

Tags: shell, io-redirection

I'm using IO redirection to log output to a log file. But I want to able to move the log to a different file whenever the current day changes, such as `2017-08-18.log`.

My attempts included to use `>xxx.log` redirection to clear the log file, but all content reappeared within the new log?

How to set up the log redirection? Thanks.

Comment: Your question is unclear .. please post some example to explain what you want to achieve

Comment: Did you try this /etc/logrotate.d/? https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate

Comment: Hi, I have post the question to [unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/386852/how-to-clear-a-redirect-log-file-content-in-shell) and more detailed. Hope help at this site, thanks.

Comment: You can use logrotate to rotate your log automatically but you must do something like restart your log process. But I read your description, you use '>> log.log' to save log, it quite difficult. If you use java, why not you use something like log4j?

Comment: Basically what the OP is looking for is a sort of `tee` with rotating log files. I don't believe such a biest exist although it's not hard to build a custom script, see below for a perl try. I think `expect` could suit, too. And `logrotate` is no help because the computation would still have to interrupt and close its output once a while.

Answer (score 2):

If you are ok with Perl you could run this little script:

```
use POSIX qw(strftime);

$fbase = "tmp-%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M.log";

while(<>)
{
  $fnamenew = strftime $fbase, localtime;

  if ($fnamenew ne $fname)
  {
    print "logging to: $fnamenew\n";
    $fname = $fnamenew;
    close OUT;
    open OUT, ">$fname";
  }
  print OUT $_;
}
```

Use it like: `$mycomputation | perl script.pl`. It will append all input to a filename built from the given time pattern, here `tmp-YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MI.log`. On each new line of input, the pattern is rebuilt and checked against the old one. Should it differ then the input is piped to the new file and the old one is closed.

Comment: Hi, I'm not familiar with perl.The script has a error: `./perl.pl: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token (' ` and another line `./perl.pl: line 1: use POSIX qw(strftime);'`

Comment: Looks like you ran it with your shell. You need to run it with perl like so `perl script.pl` as I mentioned. Or put a `#!/usr/bin/perl` in line 1.

Comment: How to write every print to file realtime?

Comment: What's your program to run the computation?

Comment: It's a massive java process and I don't want import log4j similar library if possible. Just save println info is enough.

Comment: It's ok. Just run the process like shown above: `process | perl script.pl`. If you need to observe the output you could `tail -f tmp-...log`.

Comment: Maybe some misleading, with your script, the print result will save to file only at the end of the minutes.So, the `tail` command only affect at the end of minutes.How can I watch the log file realtime?

Comment: You could try this `myprocess | tee /dev/tty | perl script.pl`.

Comment: Sorry for just additionally print to console. File's message also write at the end of minutes.I can write the pipe script with other language, thanks a lot, It's really a good thought.